# PHP: wait 2 minute until next, is this right?

Tags: php

```
$timenow = time();
if($lasttime - 120 > $timenow)
```

Is this right? to check if there has been 2 minutes ( 120 seconds ) since lasttime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's either `$lasttime + 120 > $timenow` or `$timenow - 120 > $lasttime`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine both times start with 0 and the "timenow" grows with every second. With that mindtrick you should get it.

Answer (score 0):

`if (($lasttime+120)>=time())`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to calculate number of elapsed seconds first, then compare it to your needs:

```
$elapsed_time = time() - $lasttime; ## time() is increasing
if ($elapsed_time > 120) {
    ## more then 2 minutes passed
}
else {
    ## it's not time yet
}
```

This should help to understand your code later.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
//Do whatever
if ($time_start-microtime(true)>=2000){
    //Yup, 2 minutes
}
```

Comment: That will only work if exactly 2 minutes have passed, very unlikely to work.

Comment: Very bad idea, since process can hang for one milisecond, and you will "miss" the 2 minutes delay.